# WebSphere 8.5 with Grails 3.x

Tags: grails, war, websphere-8, contextroot

I'm trying to deploy an app developed in Grails 3.0.x at WebSphere 8.5.5

I've generated .war file and installed successfully but, when I'm trying to access through link http://localhost:9080/myContext/ following error appears:

> Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: {0}

I've added context-path to app at application.yml file with the same name I put in WAS install settings but error continues.

I apprecciate so much if someone could help me to fix this error.

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: When I upgraded to Grails 3.0.x, I found it difficult to get it running anything but Tomcat. So I suggest you try first with Tomcat.

Comment: I run the app in tomcat and it works fine. But I don't know why in WAS appears this message.

I've included parameters from Grails documentation for WAS and don't work. :(

Comment: Please try a more recent version of Grails 3.1.x, people have deployed successfully to WAS https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10133